# Правильный синтаксис с возврата Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Всем привет. Сервер возвращает следующее

```
return['error']=0;
$return['message'] = 'Информация была успешна заменена';
echo json_encode($return);
```

На jquery ловлю так

```
success: function (data, textStatus) {
            console.log(data);

        }
```

Данные возвращаются, в консоле появляются, но если я хочу вывести только message

```
success: function (data, textStatus) {
                console.log(data.message);

            }
```

То пишит undefined

Как правильно вывести?

Comment: так а что выводит `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @Grundy {"error":0,"message":"\u0418\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f \u0431\u044b\u043b\u0430 \u0443\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0448\u043d\u0430 \u0437\u0430\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0430"}

Comment: что выводит `console.log(typeof data)`?

Comment: @Grundy string выводит

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо! Помогли))) хы

Comment: тогда тебе просто не хватает полученную строку перевести в объект: `JSON.parse(data).message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил отправку данных json

dataType : "json",